# ¿Por que cuando descargo un proyecto de github en tortoise, me crea dos carpetas (branch y trunk)?

Tags: github, svn

Mi problema es que al tratar de descargar mi aplicacion de el repositorio de `github` por medio de `tortoise svn`, se crean dos nuevas carpetas en el interior de el folder donde descargue mi aplicacion, la aplicacion se descarga correctamente, las carpetas que se crean son `trunk` y `branch`. Lo que yo quiero es evitar que esas carpetas se creen y que solo me descargue las carpetas de mi aplicacion que esta en `github`, ya que de la forma actual no puedo mantener correctamente mi control de versiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El sistema principal de github es git, Subversion funciona de una forma diferente.
Mientras git gestiona las branches de manera separada al working directory, Subversion utiliza el propio workingdirectory para gestionar las branches.

Cuando utilizas el puente de github con subversion, la carpeta *trunk* contiene la branch a la que apunte el *HEAD* de git.

Mi recomendación si vas a usar github es utilizarlo con un cliente de git, en lugar de utilizar subversion.